# "k-Swap SAT" problem

Tags: reference-request, sat, parameterized-complexity

I would like to know if the following NP-complete problem has a name and has been studied:

> **Input:** Given a CNF formula $\varphi$ on $n$ variables, a truth assignment $\sigma:[n] \to \{T,F\}$ and an integer $k$;
>   **Question:** Can we transform $\sigma$  into a *satisfying assignment* for $\varphi$, *swapping* the truth values of at most $k$ pairs of variables.

It is very similar to the problem k-FLIP SAT (see [my previous question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33604/3247) for details); but here the number of truth values used cannot change.

In particular, I would like to know if there are some results about its parameterized complexity in the general case and under some restrictions (e.g. q-CNF formulas, max occurrences of a variable).

I did a few searches on google, but didn't find anything (but probably I'm not using the correct terms).

Comment: You may want to look at random k-SAT and phase transition litriture and the structure of the space of solutions.

Comment: E.g. see the work by Achlioptas and colleagues. If the clause ratio is in the hard section the closest solution to randomly selected assignment is $\Theta(n)$  far if I recall correctly.

Comment: I think it is W[1]-hard by a reduction from the parameterized 2-SAT problem.In this problem we are given a 2-SAT instance, and the goal is to find a satisfying assignment with at most k ones.

Comment: Yes. For a Min-Ones-2-Sat instance, start from the all-0 assignment, add k dummy variables whose truth values do not affect the satisfiability of the formula, and set them to 1.

Comment: @IgorShinkar: thanks! Meanwhile I found a W[1]-hardness reduction from independent set (that - I bet - is probably similar to the one used for Min-Ones-2-Sat). If you want convert the comment to an answer (the technique suggested by Serge is ok) but I'll wait to see is someone has a reference/known name for the problem.

Comment: @Serge Gaspers isn’t Min-Ones 2-SAT FPT by local search? I agree with Marzio De Biasi that the problem asked about is W[1]-hard (by reduction from Clique or Independent Set) though.

Comment: @daniello: I agree. Sorry for the oversight. One can reduce from Min-Ones-Sat instead, which is W[2]-hard.